# how to index my collection to use a compound multikey index

Tags: mongodb

this is my document i want to query:

```
{
"_id":ObjectId("5062d30522dfae0e11000000"),
"id_resource" : "147",
"moment_created" : ISODate("2012-03-22T16:29:21Z"),
"moment_updated" : ISODate("2012-03-22T16:29:21Z"),
"users_involved" : [
    {
        "id_user" : "113928869",
        "state" : "answered",
        "id_folder" : "0",
        "is_deleted" : "0"
    },
    {
        "id_user" : "121624627",
        "state" : "new",
        "id_folder" : "0",
        "is_deleted" : "0" }
],
"posts" : [
    {
        "id_author" : "113928869",
        "post" : "hiohhio",
        "moment_created" : ISODate("2012-03-22T16:29:21Z")
    }
    ]
}
```

and this is how i tried to ensure my index:

```
db.message.ensureIndex({id_resource:1, users_involved : 1});
```

and this is the query i used to query my collection :

```
db.message.find({id_resource : "143", "users_involved" : {$elemMatch : {id_user : "101226353", state : "answered"}}});
```

but one explain later i get this output:

```
{
    "clusteredType" : "ParallelSort",
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "n" : 11,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "nYields" : 8624,
    "nscanned" : 1461277,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1461277,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1461277,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1461277,
    "millisShardTotal" : 1878,
    "millisShardAvg" : 939,
    "numQueries" : 2,
    "numShards" : 2,
    "millis" : 1646
```

}

getIndexes will return:

```
[
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "messaging.message",
            "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "id_resource" : 1,
                    "users_involved" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "messaging.message",
            "name" : "id_resource_1_users_involved_1"
    }
```

]

sadly i do not understand why my query is not using the index id_resource_1_users_involved_1. Can anyone explain to me why my index is not used or how i have to build my index to support the query i want to use?

thx for time and help

## UPDATE

shame on me, a typo on my side. So here is the actual explain of the query

```
{
    "clusteredType" : "ParallelSort",
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor id_resource_1_users_involved_1",
    "n" : 5,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "nYields" : 2,
    "nscanned" : 46868,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 93736,
    "nscannedObjects" : 46868,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 93736,
    "millisShardTotal" : 281,
    "millisShardAvg" : 140,
    "numQueries" : 2,
    "numShards" : 2,
    "millis" : 220
```

}

so the query IS using my index but it is still slow , also nscanned is pretty big, so not the whole index is used? i will have to check if nscanned matches the amount of messages for resource x

using the compound index from JohnnyHK it got much much faster:

```
ensureIndex({id_resource:1, 'users_involved.id_user':1, 'users_involved.state':1});
```

explain

```
{
    "clusteredType" : "ParallelSort",
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor id_resource_1_users_involved.id_user_1_users_involved.state_1",
    "n" : 5,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 7,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 7,
    "nscannedObjects" : 7,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 7,
    "millisShardTotal" : 0,
    "millisShardAvg" : 0,
    "numQueries" : 2,
    "numShards" : 2,
    "millis" : 1
}
```

so if i want to query the users_involved array i have to build a seperate index for every query?

also @JohnnyHK using the whole array as mentioned like:

```
find({id_resource : "197", "users_involved" : {$elemMatch : {id_user : "128825371", state : "answered", id_folder:"0", is_deleted:"0"}}}).hint("id_resource_1_users_involved_1")
```

did not improve anything, explain:

```
{
    "clusteredType" : "ParallelSort",
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor id_resource_1_users_involved_1",
    "n" : 5,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "nYields" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 46868,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 46868,
    "nscannedObjects" : 46868,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 46868,
    "millisShardTotal" : 222,
    "millisShardAvg" : 111,
    "numQueries" : 2,
    "numShards" : 2,
    "millis" : 174
```

}

or maybe i am still doing it wrong?

*also i removed the shard information from the explain response, if this information may be important just say so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your compound index includes the whole `users_involved` array, the index can only be used when matching complete embedded document elements of the array.  See [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-UsingDocumentsasKeys).

I think you'd be better served using a compound index that includes just the fields from `users_involved` that you intend to search on.  So either:

```
db.message.ensureIndex({id_resource:1, 'users_involved.id_user' : 1});
```

**OR**

```
db.message.ensureIndex({id_resource:1, 'users_involved.id_user' : 1, 'users_involved.state' : 1});
```

Comment: @braunbaer You don't have to build a separate index for each query, but you need to make sure that the indexes you define provide enough selectivity so that only a handful of documents need to be scanned in any given query.  See [the docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-CompoundKeys) on compound keys.

Comment: well i ment every new case (query) would be a new index. 

case "resource x player y folder z" -> index resource_player_folder

case "resource x player y state z" -> index resource_player_state

case "resource x player x folder z state xz" -> index resource_player_state_folder

the idea was to create an index over "users_invovled" without having these seprate indexes for nearly the same query. But maybe i just have to read the docs many many times to actualy understand them. Thx for your time and help.